# Computers disappear and reappear in SCCM console

Tags: sccm

We have a specific location with seven computers in it and for some reason, only one computer at a time will show up in the SCCM console.  The computer that shows up is random and this changes frequently.  So if this location has computers A to G, Computer C may show up and then a few minutes later, Computer C is gone and Computer E shows up and it continues in that manner.

There's nothing special about this location and the computers are set up the same as they are everywhere else.  Our SCCM admin suggested that it may have something to do with duplicate GUIDs, but he doesn't have time to look into this right now, so that's why I'm here.

We're running console version 5.1802.1082.1800 and clients are on version 5.00.8634.1010 with Windows 7.  We have about 1,200 clients, but we're not having this issue anywhere else.  I see that there are a lot of SCCM logs, but I'm not very familiar with SCCM, so I'm not sure which ones to examine, nor what to look for.

I wasn't able to find this issue anywhere on the internet.  Has anyone experienced this before?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to suggest this question be moved over to our sister site ServerFault where enterprise IT stuff is the name of the game.

Comment: If the SMS GUID in Control Panel --> Configuration Manager is the same on these machines, this is the issue. SCCM would think these are all the same machine. Were these machines cloned?

Comment: You are correct, the GUIDs are the same.  They were cloned, but so were the computers in other locations and they have different GUIDs.  Also, we used images with the SCCM installed on them for most of the computers in the company and I confirmed that several computers set up with the same image also have different GUIDs.  I checked with the fellow who set these up and he can't see anything different he did with these computers that he wouldn't have done with the others.

Comment: So while I know what the issue is, I now need to figure out how to resolve it.  I tried uninstalling the client, deleting the certificates, deleting "C:\Windows\SMSCFG.ini", and reinstalling with the RESETKEYINFORMATION=TRUE parameter, but even though it generates a new GUID, it reverts back to the old one a few minutes later.  Once we resolve this, I'll post the solution.  If anyone else has any other suggestions, I'm happy to hear them :)

Comment: I would say the most probable reason why the old stuff comes back is that something gets merged with the old object on the server, so it would be best to delete that and afterwards reinstall the client. One other possible problem is something we had sometimes with industrial pcs in our environment where the hardware vendor failed to provide a unique bios guid for their computers which confused the sccm. You can check that with "wmic path win32_computersystemproduct get uuid" it has to be different on each pc (not super likely given your description of the problem however)